# Linux- cannot create folder in restricted area

Tags: xubuntu

I am new to linux - ubuntu (desktop). I have install Xampp which is working fine, now I need to create directory at /opt/lampp but cannot create due to permission level. I am using admin account, also I run script at terminal "gksu ./nautilus &"; followed by it asked me password but nothing happening after that. My friend run same command and it works for him. I have install linux on VM

many thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/lampp/<folder-name>
```

You'll be prompted for the root password.

Comment: no it doesn't create neither ask me password

Comment: If as root you can't create a folder you may need to stop the daemons (services) I'm not an expert on this. Then try the command again

Comment: No problem, I'm happy I could help with this.

Comment: @toxic If this answer satisfies your question, please mark it as "accepted".